# Why that richfaces tree example does not work?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Hi
   I have written a simple example for richfaces tree tag, but it only expands root nodes (but does not collapse them back)
the xhtml code:

```
   <rich:panel id="unitTest" width="240" height="400">
      <h:form>
      <rich:tree>
         <rich:recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor roots="#{tree.nodes}" var="item" nodes="#{item.nodes}" >
            <rich:treeNode>
               <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
            </rich:treeNode> 
         </rich:recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor>
      </rich:tree>
      </h:form>
   </rich:panel>
```

java bean code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class UnitTreeNode
{
   String name;
   List<UnitTreeNode> children;

   public UnitTreeNode()
   {
      this.name="";
   }
   public UnitTreeNode(String name)
   {
      this.name=name;
   }
   public List<UnitTreeNode> getNodes() 
   {
      if(children==null)
      {
         children=new ArrayList<UnitTreeNode>();
         for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
           children.add(new UnitTreeNode(name+i));
      }
      return children;
   }
   public String toString()
   {
      return name;
   }
}
```

config:

```
   <managed-bean>
      <managed-bean-name>tree</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>UnitTreeNode</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
   </managed-bean>
```

I am using myfaces 1.2.8 and richfaces 3.3.2.SR1, and I cannot see why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is by default tree switchType is ajax and your ajax requests are not getting properly submitted to server due to the surrounding  tag.(Seems to be a bug with rich faces implementation and it may be solved with later releases).

So here is the solution

1. use `<rich:tree switchType="server">`
2. or just remove the `<h:form>` tag

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on faces 3.3.3, setting facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE to false in my web.xml did it.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```